# Bitmap.LockBits: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap

```
//Rectangle is of same size as image   
//image.PixelFormat = Format8bppIndexed
var w= image.Width,                h= image.Height;
var bmpData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat);
```

i do convert to 32/24bppIndexed Pixel format to 8bpp,  before calling Lockbits
No problm with it and
I tried with png, bmp it works & LockBits works too
but LockBits doesnt work successfully with TIF image type.
i tried converting TIF to bmp,png but no luck. (TIF to any format, fails)
i dont see any difference setting ImageLockMode.ReadOnly vs ImageLockMode.ReadWrite
Security Permission is set Allow for all users

How can i make Lockbits work for TIF types?

Should i go for Alternate version of LockBits as in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/625868/LockBits-alternative-SecurityException-workaround

No problem with other sections of code, as i said it works with some formats.

Comment: TIFF, BMP and PNG are image format types, they only matter for the image file on disk.  Once you create an Image object from them then the encoding detail disappears.  Now the PixelFormat is super important.  And you can't just arbitrarily assign it.  Format8bppIndexed is particularly troublesome, it requires a color table to map a byte to a color.   You don't have one when you start with a 24bpp or 32bpp image and creating one is very tricky.  Hard to map 24 million possible colors to just 256 colors and still make it look good.  Not supported by .NET, AForge.NET is a popular library.